# How can I create multiple relationships in MS Access at one time?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, key, relationship

I feel that this should be a simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

I have an MS Access database where all the key fields have their proper key icon when I view the tables, but no relationships are defined. I need to create relationships between the "UnitID" key field for all the data tables. Some relationships are one-to-one and others are one-to-many (or one to none), but that doesn't matter, I don't need to enforce referential integrity. I just need to query the database, and worked with the query result tables, not add anything or change the data. All the UnitID fields have the same name.

Right now, I am just pulling up the relationship tab and dragging-and-dropping the names for each table, which takes forever. I can use the edit relationships icon that brings up a form, but it still needs to be re-opened for each table.

I am working with a government, publicly downloadable Access database. I realize Access isn't ideal, but that is the format it comes in and the program I'm am supposed to use for my job.

If there is a way to do it in the interface, that would be the best, since I can share it directly with others in my office who are unfamiliar with macros. But I have used VBA before for Excel and know some basic SQL. I've never used macros in Access, so I don't know what their capacities are; can this be done if there is no in-built functionality?

Comment: A database can function just fine without defining relationships. To enforce relational integrity Relationships must be defined in the backend of split db. Since you don't want that, Relationships can be defined in frontend but only benefit is to query builder which will use defined relationships to build JOIN clause in query. Building code to programmatically establish relationships might take as long as just manually setting relationships. If this is a one-time occurrence, why bother with code?

Comment: How many data tables are there?

Comment: Thanks! there are about 50 tables, but this isn't just a one time job, I will have to do it again, not sure of the frequency right now. The Query Design function is the problem, I need to query the data in a whole bunch of ways and output tables. It doesn't work if I don't define the relationships (I tried, wishful thinking). If I input a SQL query --"SQL view"-- in Access, will it work without defining the relationships? Sort of defeats the purpose of Access, but it might solve my issue...

Comment: If I get what you are asking, yes. But I could chose from among a number of tables to serve as a reference. The UnitID fields are universal--every table uses them to identify the source of each data record. Some tables have many entries with the same ID, and other have none. A few have secondary keys amongst themselves, but the are not common and I can do that manually very quickly if I need.

Comment: All the tables relate to one another via the UnitID. The data set is a national collection of data about colleges and every record with school-reported data has a Unit ID. It is just that some tables have multiple rows for each school and some schools aren't on some tables.

Comment: The only tables that don't have UnitIDs are the ones that have codes or other descriptors that tie into or describe the other data. Those I can manage by hand since almost all the codes are in only a few tables

Comment: sort of, yes--I can get around it by linking each table to the reference table I pick and then making sure that in the Query Design I always include the one reference table I have chosen, and add the UnitID from that table to every query. That seems to work. But ultimately it's an arbitrary choice, and if I need others to use the database--which I likely will down the line--I'm worried about it breaking. Also, i would prefer to just query what I want to output

Comment: Look, you don't have to worry about it, I'll figure it out. I might be able to get someone else in the office to help out, it's just the school is on lockdown for COVID so I'm a bit on my own, with my personal laptop!  If you want to have a look, I am working from the datasets on this page--the 2018-2019 set  https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/use-the-data/download-access-database

Answer (score 1):

Why must you have Relationships created at all? They don't define what Queries you can run. And if you don't need Referential Integrity, then I don't see much practical use for them anyhow.

If you can't get your Queries to run, then I would look elsewhere for the root of the problem.

By the way, once you get this problem solved, consider this: you may not need to actually create any Query result Tables if they are used as *intermediate* results. Since the result of a Query is a Table, then anywhere that the syntax mentions "Table", you can insert a Query. That is, Queries can be nested inside of other Queries. I mention this because you seem to be saying that you need a whole lot of result Tables, which in itself is going to get messy, not to mention that they will take up and lot of space and, worse, will be redundant and will have to recreated whenever your source Tables change (liable to be a maintenance nightmare).

Answer (score 0):

So are you talking about the Relationship Designer Window (Database Tools | Relationships menu option) in MS Access as pictured? With all the tables added, it takes about 5 seconds to click UnitID on one table, drag/drop to UnitID on another table and click Create. I guess it might take an hour or two to do them all?

[image: MS Access Relationship Designer]